# Make a property required depending on a query parameter with OpenAPI and JSON-Schema

Tags: jsonschema, openapi

I have a REST API that support for most calls a `with` query parameter, allowing the user to specify which additional fields they want to load along with the resource’s basic data.

I can describe the query parameter with OpenAPI, and I can describe the format of the response with JSON-Schema. But how can I describe the relation between the parameter and the response?

What I want to describe is:

- `/api/resource/{id}` returns:

  ```
  {"id": 123, … }
  ```
- `/api/resource/{id}?with=stuff` returns:

  ```
  {"id": 123, …, "stuff": { … }}
  ```

I would like this `stuff` property to be defined as `required`. Is there a way of doing this?

(What makes this probably even more impossible is that the value of `with` can be a comma-separated list of properties, but at this point I’m not hoping)

Answer (score 2):

You can't do anything in JSON Schema using out of context data. So, the only way to do what you want is to put the query data into your response.

```json
{
  "id": 123,
  "query": {},
  ...
}
```

```json
{
  "id": 123,
  "with": ["stuff"],
  ...
  "stuff": { ... }
}
```

With pure JSON Schema or OpenAPI 3.1, you can use `if`/`then` and `contains` to express the conditional requirement.

```json
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "id": { "type": "object" },
    "with": { "type": "array", "items": { "type": "string" } },
    ...
    "stuff": { ... }
  },
  "required": ["id"],

  "allOf": [
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "with": { "contains": { "const": "stuff" } }
        },
        "required": ["with"]
      },
      "then": { "required": ["stuff"] }
    },
    ... additional conditionals ...
  ]
}
```

However, assuming you are on OpenAPI 3.0, you don't have `if`, `then`, or `contains`. It's still possible, but it gets a bit ugly because you need to use a bunch of confusing boolean logic concepts instead.

```json
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "id": { "type": "object" },
    "with": { "type": "array", "items": { "type": "string" } },
    ...
    "stuff": { ... }
  },
  "required": ["id"],

  "allOf": [
    {
      "anyOf": [
        {
          "not": {
            "properties": {
              "with": {
                "not": {
                  "items": { "not": { "enum": ["stuff"] } }
                 }
              }
            },
            "required": ["with"]
          }
        },
        { "required": ["stuff"] }
      ]
    },
    ... additional conditionals ...
  ]
}
```

Comment: Good idea! I’m using JSON-Schema (with `if`/`then`) for describing the format of the response, and referencing those schemas in my OpenAPI 3.0 file. Not sure if this is unusual or a bad idea, but as soon as OpenAPI 3.1 is more widely supported by my tooling, it should all be compatible.

Answer (score 0):

JSON schema: query string required

```
 schema: {
  tags: ["sample"],
  summary: "Set query string values to required",
  querystring: {
    type: "object",
    properties: {
      name: {
        type: "string",
      },
      address: {
        type: "string",
      },
    },
    required: ["name"],
  },
},
```